# How to delete record from DB having composite key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have asp.net app where I am using gridview for data showing, editing and deleting. Now I want to delete or edit record from table and I need to pass 3 cols in DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"colName"). how i can do this?

**EDITED**

> Basically when i need to update or
>   delete record from asp.net app, I have
>   to pass values of 3 columns (which are
>   composite keys) to my UDF. Now How I
>   can pass 3 different values to
>   DataBinder.Eval() and reading them in
>   GridView Rowcommand event.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not understand the context; if you really need to pass "three in one", you could concatenate them in a string and split up later again like

```
string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", key1, key2, key3)
```

and later, split it up again with

```
string.Split('-')
```

to have the separated values again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you have such tasks, it is better to just add primary key to your database table.